# Make dll callback in unreal

Tags: c++, dll, unreal-engine5

I try make dll callback. I make worked solution, but it use void function without my class, and i cant make some logic here. I try rework logic CatchErrorFunc to UWebClientHandler::CatchErrorFunc, and no see right way.

```
#include "WebClientHandler.h"
#include "WebController.h"
#include "Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/Paths.h"

void *DLLHandlerGet;
typedef void (* StringCallbackVoidF)(const char *data);
StringCallbackVoidF PtrCatchErrorFunc;
void CatchErrorFunc(const char* msg);
typedef void(*GetErrorCallbackVoidF)(StringCallbackVoidF callback);

void UWebClientHandler::Init()
{
    Super::Init();
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler: init"));
    
    ImportDLL();
    RegCallBack();
    TestCallback();
}

bool UWebClientHandler::ImportDLL()
{
    FString folder = "WebSocketClient";
    FString fileName = "websocket-sharp.dll";   
    FString filePath = *FPaths::ProjectPluginsDir() + folder + "/" + fileName;  
    if (FPaths::FileExists(filePath))
    {
        //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler:ImportDLL: dll path exist"));
        DLLHandlerGet = FPlatformProcess::GetDllHandle(*filePath); // Retrieve the DLL.
        if (DLLHandlerGet != nullptr)
        {
            //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler:ImportDLL: dll TRUE"));
            return true;
        }
        //UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler:ImportDLL: dll FALSE"));
    }
    return false;       
}

void UWebClientHandler::RegCallBack()
{
    if (DLLHandlerGet == nullptr)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler: DLL is Null"));
        return;
    }

    const FString RegisterErrorString = "RegisterErrorCB";
    GetErrorCallbackVoidF GetCatchErrorVoid = (GetErrorCallbackVoidF)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(PtrCatchErrorFunc, *RegisterErrorString);
    if (GetCatchErrorVoid != nullptr)
    {   
        PtrCatchErrorFunc = &CatchErrorFunc;
        GetCatchErrorVoid(PtrCatchErrorFunc);   
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler: PtrCatchError reg = DONE"));
    }
    
}

void UWebClientHandler::TestCallback()
{
    if (DLLHandlerGet == nullptr)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler: DLL is Null"));
        return;
    }
    const FString ConnectString = "Connect";

    typedef void (* ActionCallbackVoidF)();
    ActionCallbackVoidF PtrConnect = (ActionCallbackVoidF)FPlatformProcess::GetDllExport(DLLHandlerGet, *ConnectString);    
    if (PtrConnect != nullptr)
    {   
        PtrConnect();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler: Connect()"));
    }
}

//NOT WORKING
//void UWebClientHandler::CatchErrorFunc(const char* msg){ UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler. EVENT ERROR:  %hs"),msg); }

//WORK FINE
void CatchErrorFunc(const char* msg){ UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("UWebClientHandler. EVENT ERROR:  %hs"),msg); }
```

I can use here static void to my class

```
void CatchError(const char* msg) {UWebHandlerSubsystem::MakeCatchErrorEvent(msg);}

void UWebHandlerSubsystem::MakeCatchErrorEvent(const char* msg)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning,TEXT("WebController. EVENT ERROR:  %hs"),msg);
    OnErrorEvent("");
}
```

But its static class, i cant use some logic here - example: i need blueprint event, but BlueprintImplementableEvent not work in static methods.

Comment: Please have a look at [mre] – this code certainly is not *'minimal'* and neither complete (class declaration of `UWebClientHandler` lacks)…

Comment: Not fully clear about your problem description either; am I correct if I interpret it this way: *'You have a member function `UWebClientHandler::CatchErrorFunc` – but you cannot use it in the callback* unless *you make it static, in which case, though, you cannot access the non-static data members.'*?

Comment: There's a fundamental problem about member-functions, though: They need an object to be called on (`UWebClientHandler h; h.CatchErrorFunc("")`), but there is no such one. It looks as if `GetCatchErrorVoid` is the function in question requiring the callback – if so, are you in control of? Then change the type to `void gcev(void(*callback)(char const* msg, void* userData), void* userData)`, in this case you can pass both a static function (member functions have different call mechanism!) and the object in question to.

Answer (score 0):

From the code fragments I have the impression (correct me if I'm wrong) that you are incorrectly describing global C functions as 'static' functions.

Using the `static` keyword you can also declare **class members** and **class methods** as `static`. (This also has nothing todo with a '*static library'* by the way) First read up on that keyword so that you understand the difference between global functions / local functions and indeed also static and extern **functions**.

It also helps if you understand the difference between *static* and *shared* libraries. I mention this because what actually works to exporting a function in a *static library* (i.e. using the `extern` keyword) does *not* work for shared libraries.

To export symbols (**functions**, **variables**, **class members** and **methods**) from a shared library module (i.e.a .dll & .lib on Windows) you'd need to tag the symbol declaration in de header as follows:

- with `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the library itself
- with `__declspec(dllimport)` when including the header in a different project. There's plenty of material online that describes how to do this exactly.

But despite all this, the main problem will be the fact that the event context that is needed to generate/process that event data is probably not available externally, unless you either use an Unreal API call or you go through the hassle of replicating it at the other side.